# SQL to find rows with a non-zero value for X and a zero value for Y?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am working in BigQuery. I have some data that looks like this:

```
org     code    spend
A81001  0121    33.4
A81002  0121    45.2
A81003  0121    7.3
A81001  0122    10.1
A81002  0122    10.1
```

I want to find all organisations with a non-zero spend on `0121`, and a zero spend on `0122`. Can I do this in a single query?

I'm not sure if this is an aggregate query, or what.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT org
FROM mytable
WHERE code IN ('0121', '0122')
GROUP BY org
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN code = '0121' THEN spend ELSE 0 END) <> 0 AND
       SUM(CASE WHEN code = '0122' THEN spend ELSE 0 END) = 0
```

Comment: Thanks. What kind of query would you call that, does it have a name other than `HAVING`? (so I know what to Google for next time?)

Comment: @Richard This is called *conditional aggregation* and it standard ANSI SQL syntax.